# Problem with the scaffold component in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, scaffold

I have a problem with my android applicatiopn in kotlin. I am trying to use the scaffold dependency to make a test screen, as to see if the component can render.

However, they seem to be a problem in syntax that I don't see, as the IDE clearly tells me it has no idea what innerPadding is.

What could I have missed?

[Snippet of code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygjw0.png)